# How to get audio/video files from iPhone library and save it to application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad, video-codecs

How to get audio/video files from iPhone library and save it to application?. I need to save songs/video to my application so if user delete it from library then also availbale with the application.

Thanks In Advance.